# How to save or open an html file via ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm sending a pure ajax call by `XMLHttpRequest` to a web service which can return either pdf or html. I know how to handle pdf, but how can I can I handle and download or **better open** the html? I've tried but it open a returned html page without css styles. In particular, what `req.responseType` should I set and how should I save or **better open** an incoming html file in `req.onload = function(data) { .... ???? }`?

Comment: Why are you using Ajax if you want the browser to open it as if you'd just requested it normally? Just request it normally in the first place.

Comment: @Quentin, it's generated and can take a lot of time.

Comment: @jawanam is it some kind of report?

Comment: use an iframe and set the src to the url - your question is missing some context

Comment: `better open the html`? Open it WHERE? in a browser? don't have to do anythign to "open" html - just stuff the html into a dom tree and the browser'll render it.

Comment: @MarcB, in order to do that, my man, I have to receive it first. via ajax. reread my question.